# Python: While loop exceeded the condition

Tags: python, arraylist, while-loop, conditional-statements, difflib

I wrote the code below to generate a list containing 25 lists, where each of them has 40 elements. However, the main issue is to have a low level of similarity between the sequenced elements of the all the lists (I tried to apply SequenceMatcher from difflib). Although the condition is to stop the loop when the number of inner lists = 25, I get 32 inner lists.

Here is my code:

```
import random
from difflib import SequenceMatcher


def string_converter(input_list):
    string = ""
    for m in input_list:
        string += str(m)
    return string


lists = []
strings = []
e = 0

while e <= 25:
    list_one = []
    n = 0
    for i in range(40):
        if 7 < n < 33:
            i = random.randint(0, 3)
            list_one.append(i)
            n += 1
        else:
            i = random.randint(0, 2)
            list_one.append(i)
            n += 1
    list_string = string_converter(list_one)
    if e == 0:
        strings.append(list_string)
        lists.append(list_one)
        e = 1
    else:
        for s in strings:
            if SequenceMatcher(None, list_string, s).ratio() < 0.7:
                strings.append(list_string)
                lists.append(list_one)
                e += 1

print(e)
print(lists)
print(len(lists))
print(strings)
```

Comment: maybe u wna do `while len(lists) <= 25` instead of `while e <= 25` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this loop, which can append multiple copies of `list_one` to `lists` as you iterate over `strings`:

```
for s in strings:
    if SequenceMatcher(None, list_string, s).ratio() < 0.7:
        strings.append(list_string)
        lists.append(list_one)
        e += 1
```

What you need to do is check if *all* `SequenceMatcher` values are `<0.7` and only append if they are. Something like this:

```
if all(SequenceMatcher(None, list_string, s).ratio() < 0.7 for s in strings):
    strings.append(list_string)
    lists.append(list_one)
    e += 1
```

Comment: it gave me an error telling:  . if all(SequenceMatcher(None, list_string, s).ratio() < 0.7):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: @KarimYosefRezk you need to include the iterator part: `all(SequenceMatcher(None, list_string, s).ratio() < 0.7 for s in strings)`

Comment: last question : it returned 26 not 25, Could you tell me the interpretation please ?

Comment: @KarimYosefRezk it's because you have `e <= 25` so `e` counts `0, 1, 2, ..., 25` which is 26 values. Just change that test to `e < 25`